# Show website before logging in to Windows

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have recently been asked by some people if i can help develop/deploy a solution that allows their staff to first login into their website before being able to do anything on their systems. They fear their staffs dont visit their website and will like to do this so that the first thing a staff sees before he can use his/her desktop is their website.

Please can any body give me any pointers?

Any .net related code article will be welcome, as well as maybe already built solutions.
Thanks

Comment: You can always modify the computer's policies to pop-up the browser with the specific web page. Try to ask over at http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Before login there is no real desktop... doing what you describe might be technically possible (probably some "hacks" will be needed)... BUT it goes against any security measures to do so..

An option might be to setup the Windows AutoStart in a way that is launches the browser with that website...

As per comment:

you can find some ideas on how to deal with "startup items" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/how-to-access-or-modify-startup-items-in-the-window-registry.aspx) and [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94010-running-your-program-on-windows-startup-either-the-current-user-or-the/).

Comment: Ok,do you have any idea how to setup the windows autostart

Comment: @Layinka see my EDIT and 2 links above...